# Three.js - Animation of points in point cloud

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I created a point cloud of IcosahedronGeometry and animated the size of the points and when the animation happens, all points animate together but what I want is to animate each point individually and randomly. Like stars flickering but every star flicker differently. I hope you get my point. I want every point to have it's own random animation, not together.
Here's my code

```
var size = 3.8;

var particleMat2 = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    size: size,
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('/texture/particle.jpg'),
    color: 0xffffff,
    transparent: true,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    opacity: 0.1
});

var particleGeo2 = new THREE.IcosahedronBufferGeometry(27, 1);

var particleSystem2 = new THREE.Points(
    particleGeo2,
    particleMat2
);

particleSystem2.name = 'particleSystem2';

scene.add(particleSystem2);

//................Renderer

function render() {
    stats.update();

    webGLRenderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);

    var timeElapsed = clock.getElapsedTime();

    var particleSystem2 = scene.getObjectByName('particleSystem2');

    particleSystem2.material.size = (noise.simplex2(timeElapsed * 2, timeElapsed * 2) + 3.5);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the source code of this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_custom_attributes_points)

Comment: @prisoner849 thanks, will look through it.